# Java Telnet Server: Access a method from another class

Tags: java, server, telnet

Here i have got an little telnet server:
http://bits.works/view/12a997df#L44

On line 63 with the method out.println(); i can send a message to the client. 
Now I'd like to access the method out.println(); from class meineklasse?

```
class meineklasse
{

tuwas(String line)
{
out.println(line);
}
}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Make the method public?

Comment: What method `out.println()`? Do you mean `System.out.println()`?

Comment: As EJP mentioned your code is referencing System.out.println().

Comment: I don't mean System.out.....

Comment: out.println() sends a message to a telnet client

Comment: Could you pass `out` as a parameter of constructor of `meineklasse` and store it as a private attribute? That way, you could use it from anywhere in `meineklasse` without any risk of unwanted buffering since you would use the same `PrintStream` throughout the application.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Do you have an example for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass `out` in your constructor:

```
class meineklasse
{
    private PrintStream out;

    meineklasse(PrintStream out) {
        this.out = out;
    }
    tuwas(String line)
    {
        out.println(line); // perfectly defined now because out is an attribute
    }

}
```

And you use it that way:

```
      meineklasse meins =new meineklasse(out);
      meins.tuwas(line);
```

Comment: Noteworthy:

This is a type of dependency injection called * Constructor Injection*.